# Opposite of "in front of"

Tags: prepositions, antonyms

I would like to modify the following sentence to change the location of the promoter to the opposite side.

"TK promoter in front of the ICP27 gene in both vectors"

---

Would it be as following??
"TK promoter at back of the ICP27 gene in both vectors"

Comment: What exactly does "in front of" imply here? Why is *behind* not the natural choice? Can you expand?

Comment: You nee to give the full sentence of the original. Is a 'promoter' another gene in the sequence? Or is it a process that applies to the gene? Or to the vector? We're not geneticists here. In fact, that may give you a clue that it might be better to ask this on Biology.SE.

Answer (score 1):

According to Oxford Dictionary:

'at the back of smth'

'in back of smth'

'behind smth'.